# HTML -> PDF in Go

Tags: go

First time writing a Go script, just looking for feedback on language usage etc.

Using chromedp to run a headless (I think) browser to load some html, generate a PDF and then save the PDF to the file system.

````golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"

    "github.com/chromedp/cdproto/page"
    "github.com/chromedp/chromedp"
)

const PATH = "./../../"

func main() {
    source := fmt.Sprintf("%s%s", PATH, "public/index.html")
    dest := fmt.Sprintf("%s%s", PATH, "public/cv.pdf")

    htmlBuf, err := readHtml(source)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    ctx, cancel := chromedp.NewContext(context.Background())
    defer cancel()

    ts := createTestServer(htmlBuf)
    defer ts.Close()

    var buf []byte

    if err := chromedp.Run(ctx, htmlToPdf(ts.URL, &buf)); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if err := writePdf(dest, &buf); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func createTestServer(buf []byte) (*httptest.Server) {
    return httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, string(buf))
    }))
}

func writePdf(dest string, buf *[]byte) error {
    return ioutil.WriteFile(dest, *buf, 0644)
}

func readHtml(source string) ([]byte, error) {
    return ioutil.ReadFile(source)
}

func htmlToPdf(url string, res *[]byte) chromedp.Tasks {
    return chromedp.Tasks{
        chromedp.Navigate(url),
        chromedp.ActionFunc(func(ctx context.Context) error {
            buf, _, err := page.PrintToPDF().Do(ctx)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }

            *res = buf
            return nil
        }),
    }
}
```
````

Comment: the httptest server works, however it is not intended to be use for that purpose. You should rather use a regular http server with a static asset handler. But, this or that, ultimately both works. https://www.alexedwards.net/blog/serving-static-sites-with-go

Comment: it is little weird to use *[]byte as out argument. You could pass the out path as an argument and write directly to it within the task. or give it a callback that accepts the byte slice and do something with it. but this is not essential as there is no way to prevent that allocation. overall it appears to me it is using too many functions. I would inline most of this.

Comment: you could make use of flag package to take input argument, arguable in your case.

Comment: **dont** fmt.Sprintf your path, use filepath.Join instead. That is important.

Comment: as you are not controlling the context or using it, you could use context.TODO() instead. https://godoc.org/context#TODO

Comment: overall okish, just need more reading of the friendly manual and practice to prevent weird writings.

Comment: @mb-cbon really useful thank you

Comment: @mh-cbon you should put your comments into an answer.

Comment: source and dest: Use path.Join() instead of Sprintf

Comment: suggestion: Define var buf []byte closer to where it is used.